# What language can be used to automate web test?

Tags: automated-tests

I'm working on a Web Service which is associated with a form that requires inputs from user. The problem is the fields are quite large, approximately 200 fields need to be filled in. I would like to ask what language would serve best in this case, in term of automating inputs.
I tried Ruby with Watir, but it doesn't work as expected when dealing with iframe. So I'm looking for an alternative solution. Any feedback or suggestion would be greatly appreciated. My WS is developed using ASP.NET and Java Script.

Thanks,
Chan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) may provide the functionality you're looking for.  It is a testing framework that supports recording tests, so writing scripts is optional.  It does however provide scripting functionality in a variety of languages, including Java, C#, Ruby, Python and more.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In fact, I tried out Selenium too, but the configuration part killed me. Plus it's not compatible with VS2010. Would you provide any quick tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried WatiN? It is an open source automated test framework for Web application. And it support C# and other managed languages.